# TypeError unsupported Operand type(s) for %: Float and NoneType

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

sorry to bother you with a noob question, but I am new to Python. Basically this is a homework assignment that I cannot understand what I am doing wrong on. I think I have everything I need but I Keep getting a typeerror. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
def Main():
    Weight = float(input ("How much does your package weigh? :"))
    CalcShipping(Weight)

def CalcShipping(Weight):

    if Weight>=2:
        PricePerPound=1.10

    elif Weight>=2 & Weight<6:
        PricePerPound=2.20

    elif Weight>=6 & Weight<10:
        PricePerPound=float(3.70)

    else:
        PricePerPound=3.8

    print ("The total shipping cost will be $%.2f") % (PricePerPound) 


Main()
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you mean 'bitwise'.

Comment: @SilasRay You probably ignored _not_.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Python 3 code, right?

Comment: Embarrassing missreading on a question about boolean operations on my part, it would appear...  :)

Comment: They are both boolean, but one is logical, the other bitwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print()` function returns `None`; you probably wanted to move the `%` operation *into* the function call:

```
print ("The total shipping cost will be $%.2f" % PricePerPound)
```

Note that your `if` tests are using the [bitwise *and* operator `&`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations); you probably wanted to use [`and`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead, using boolean logic:

```
elif Weight >= 2 and  Weight < 6:
    PricePerPound = 2.20

elif Weight >= 6 and Weight < 10:
    PricePerPound = 3.70
```

or, using comparison chaining:

```
elif 2 <= Weight < 6:
    PricePerPound = 2.20

elif 6 <= Weight < 10:
    PricePerPound = 3.70
```

Looking over your tests, you test for `Weight >= 2` too early; if `Weight` is between 2 and 6 you'll match the first `if` and ignore the other statements altogether. I think you wanted:

```
PricePerPound = 1.10

if 2 <= Weight < 6:
    PricePerPound = 2.20

elif 6 <= Weight < 10:
    PricePerPound = 3.70

elif Weight >= 10:
    PricePerPound = 3.8
```

e.g. the price is 1.10, unless you have a package weighing 2 or more, after which the price goes up progressively.